# Restrict adding comments based on group permissions in Notebook - Odoo 14

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-14

I was wondering if this is possible to restrict to adding comments based on groups i have defined in the application for what i have seen the only attribute is for hiding the notebook widget but that is not what i need

```
<!-- Set log notes invisible for specific user groups-->
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="project_task_log_notes">
      <field name="name">project.task.log.notes</field>
      <field name="model">project.task</field>
      <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.view_task_form2"/>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="div[@class='oe_chatter']" position="replace">
          <group name="log" class="oe_chatter" groups="rw_project.group_project_rm">
            <div class="oe_chatter">
              <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers" />
              <field name="activity_ids" widget="mail_activity" />
              <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread" />
            </div>
          </group>
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//page[@name='description_page']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="string">Comments</attribute>
        </xpath>
      </field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO you may have the following options to resolve the issue.

1. Develop a small function which checks current logged user access rights/groups and return boolean value. Based on boolean value, you can set readonly attributes on the Comment field.
2. You may add `groups` attributes on the Comment field. And it can be only accessed by users with access rights/security groups.